# htaccess rewrite to sub-domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I have a independent site that sits within a sub-directory of a main server.

All links within the sub-directory site point to the root and I'd like to capture those and send them back to the sub-directory rather than the root.

Is this possible with htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

This will not redirect to the subdir, but make the other domain behave as if the subdir is the document-root. Which I think is even better.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase     /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seconddomain.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Gerben pointed out (whose answer you should totally go and upvote right now) you can  make the other domain behave as if the subdir is the document-root like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase     /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seconddomain.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^subdir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```

Another way to do what you are asking about is to use a `<base>` tag in your HTML documents.  One advantage of this is that you don't have extra .htaccess processing for every single document served by the web server (including all documents *not* in the subdirectory/subdomain).

If you want to do it inside .htaccess and have it redirect regardless of whether or not it is the subdomain, it would look this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} !^subdir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/$1 [L]
```