# Cakephp .htaccess : multiple domains pointing to one app

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, dns, multiple-domains

I am working on one cakePHP application. 
Now i want to configure my main domain (www.example.com) to be accesses via 'www.xyz.com' or 'www.bcd.com'. 
For this i will add the CName record in the 'www.xyz.com' or 'www.bcd.com' as 'www.example.com' then xys.com & bcd.com will point to the example.com.

But now on the xyz.com & bcd.com i can see the content of example.com, but whenever i click on any link it gives me 'URL NOT FOUND' Error.

So i tried lots of .htaccess rules but it is not working.

It is similar to the bloggers custom domain pointing. I need the same thing to be applied for my application.

Can anybody tried this before?

Comment: Do you want the site to be accessed from different domains or redirect all different domains to one domain?

Comment: Hey, i need only access, not redirection. My main hurdle is .htaccess rules in cakephp, i am not getting how do i apply  rule for this in htaccess.

Comment: So you want the same site to be accessible from multiple domains?

Comment: Well, as far as I know this is a bad idea, because you are creating duplicate content and also loosing the SEO and page rank for the same page to multiple domains.  So I would suggest you redirect all the different domains to your main domain and the site be accessible only from one domain. I have not tried your requirements before. Let me try out and get back to you.

Comment: You can host all the domains on same server and create virtual hosts for each domain to point to the same file system and database.

Comment: Thank you Virendra... You are right, i referred lots of documents about this. But I am working on a SAAS base app where i want  my users can add their custom domains & point them to their application created on my SAAS based app.

Comment: I am not very sure but may be you can do something like this If the users can have sub-domains on the main domain (e.g. Abc.domain.com, xyz.domain.com). Allow your server to serve the content to your main domain as well as any sub-domains. Then based on the sub-domain and probably a linking of the sub-domain with user in database you can display custom data to the user.

Comment: We are doing the same currently, but we need to provide custom domain support. If any user adds his domain (user.com) & add the CName of our app to his domain. Then the user.com can serve the user content from our domain.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617302/htaccess-rewrite-to-sub-domain/8617440#8617440

Comment: Thanks, But i dont need to direct the subdirecories. I have SAAS base application & where www.abc.com pointed to www.example.com should show the same content on www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

This isn't entirely an .htaccess issue - you need to first edit the server name in your web servers configuration file to serve not only example.com, but also requests coming in from xyz.com and bcd.com.

Comment: But this is the SAAS base application & for how many domains i will edit the config file on my web server? It is not a feasible way to tackle this issue.